# SOQL - ID In (Select...) matching any instead of all

Tags: soql

I am trying to figure out how to only get back records that have licenses in ALL states in list. Right now the query returns back records that match one or more of the values in the list.

Example:

```
John - Kansas, Florida, Maine, ...
Paul - Kansas, Missouri, Texas, ...
```

List of states:

states = "Kansas, Missouri"

I get back both John and Paul. I only want to get Paul as he has both Kansas and Missouri.

Query:

```
[Select *Fields*,
                    (Select *Fields*
                         FROM Account_Counselors__r
                         ORDER BY Account__r.Name ASC),
                    (Select *Fields* 
                         FROM Licenses__r
                         WHERE Status__c = 'Current'
                         ORDER BY NAME ASC
                    )
                FROM BCS__c
                WHERE Inactive__C = FALSE
                AND Title__c LIKE :hubFilter
                AND id in (select Hub_Name__c 
                            FROM LIcense__c 
                            WHERE Name IN :states)
                ORDER BY Name ASC];
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you will be able to resolve this within the SOQL query.

So the alternative is to process the results of this query in a loop. Create a Map of BCS Id to Set of states and put all the soql query results in that Map. Then go through the map again and only process the BCS's with 2 Strings in the Set. E.g.

```
Map<Id, Set<String>> bcsIdToState = Map<Id, Set<String>>();
for(BCS__c theBcs : [your query]){
   for(License__c theLic : theBcs.Licenses__r){
      if(bcsIdToState.containsKey(theBcs.Id){
         bcsIdToState.put(theBcs.Id,new Set<String>{theLic.Name});
      } else {
         bcsIdToState.get(theBcs.Id).add(theLic.Name);
      }
   }
}

for(Id bcsId : bcsIdToState.keySet()){
   if(bcsIdToState.get(bcsId).size() > 1){
      system.debug('this is a bcs that has both states');
   }  
}
```

Not as elegant as fetching the right data immediately but I don't see any smarter way right now.

Comment: You beat me to the answer. It's probably worthwhile to note that the `IN` operator is basically just a shortcut to consolidate a bunch of `OR`s on a single field, and that there is nothing in SOQL (or standard SQL that I know of) that consolidates a similar group of `AND`s. This answer could be improved if the target states were stored in a set (targetStates), and then checking if `targetStates.containsAll(bcsIdToState.get(bcsId))` and `bcsIdToState.get(bcsId).containsAll(targetStates)` as opposed to only checking the size of `bcsIdToState.get(bcsId)`

Comment: Good addition. However, the filter on the states is already part of the SOQL query so there will never be more than 2 states for 1 BSC. So I reckoned just checking the size would be more efficient. But that's probably neglectable, and your method does feel just a bit more secure :-)

Comment: @Guy The semi join selects the `BCS__c` records where at least 1 of the `License__c` records is in a target state, but the parent-child subquery pulls all of the related `License__c` records. In the OP's example, the set of states for John would include at least 3 strings (Kansas, Florida, and Maine), and would incorrectly pass the size check. After writing this comment, the `targetStates.containsAll(bcsIdToState.get(bcsId))` is only necessary if OP wants to say `which records match these states and only these states`.

Comment: The states value can have many values. I was just using two for my example. This is part of a VF page controller. The user can select 50+ values as the list of states aren't just true US states. Ex.  Kansas - Zone 1 and Kansas - Zone 2

Comment: OK. So there are 2 options left: 1) if in the results you need all the states that a matching BCS has (independent from whether or not they match the selected states) then we need to add the containsAll suggested by @Derek. 2) if you don't need the list of states but only need to know whether a BCS matches the selected states, then it will be more efficient to add a filter on selected states to the Licenses__r subquery of the SOQL query.

Comment: @DerekF I am back from vaca and just tried to use the code that you and Guy shared but I am getting an error.

Comment: Code Line:
bcsIdToState.put(theBcs.Id,new Set<string>{theLic.Name});

Error:
Incompatible value type Set<String> for Map<Id,String>

Comment: @MattM That's a pretty self-explanatory error. The map declared at the top of the example code block is `Map<Id,String>`, and you're trying to put a `Set<String>` into the map. `Set<String>` is a different type than `String`, hence the error. Solution is to replace `Map<Id,String> bcsIdToState = new Map<Id,String>();` with `Map<Id, Set<String>> bcsIdToState = new Map<Id,Set<String>>();` Also, don't forget to replace the size check with the `containsAll()` check. I Think @Guy should update his answer to reflect these comments.

Comment: thanks @DerekF! I've updated my answer. As for the containsAll we should first get confirmation on which of the 2 options is applicable.